# Go back one step in directory with CMD script

Tags: batch-file, cmd, directory

How can I go one directory back if I am currently in:

`\Warehouse\BI\Reporting Services\Install`

And i want to be in:

`\Warehouse\BI\Reporting Services\Tools`

Because I have one script there

```
SET CURDIR=%CD%
%FNR%  --cl --dir "%CURDIR%"
```

I want to change path in --dir

Comment: Your objective isn't clear. Guesses would be: `pushd` and `popd`, `cd..`, `cd/d`, replacing `%curdir%` with `"\Warehouse\BI\Reporting Services\Tools"`.

Comment: just i want to go back from current folder to one that is before that in the path \Warehouse\BI\Reporting Services\

Answer (score 1):

If the command allows it, you can simply do

```
%FNR%  --cl --dir ".."
```

But if the command needs a full path

```
for %%a in (..) do %FNR%  --cl --dir "%%~fa"
```

Comment: If i do the first one i get "C:\xxx\Reporting Services\Install .." . That's not what i want

Comment: `%FNR%  --cl --dir "..\Tools" ` or `for %%a in (..) do %FNR%  --cl --dir "%%~fa\Tools"`

Comment: @user2171512 that is the reason for "if allowed". What about the second code?